# Android Imagebutton was cutoff after rotate

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I want to create a customized `ViewGroup` which contains some ImageButtons rotated around one circle button.

[image]

Every ambient `ImageButton` was added to my viewgroup has the same layout position, which is on top and horizontal-center of viewgroup. After that, I will rotate each of them with specific angle, target is to create a ring around center button:

```
public class CustomeView extends ViewGroup {
private List<ArcButton> mArcButtons = new ArrayList<ArcButton>();

protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    // ...
    mArcBtnBound = new RectF(0, 0, (mInnerRadius + mThickness), mThickness);
    mArcBtnBound.offsetTo(
            getPaddingLeft() + (mInnerRadius + mThickness) / 2,
            getPaddingTop());

    for(ArcButton arcBtn: mArcButtons) {
        arcBtn.layout(
                (int)mArcBtnBound.left,
                (int)mArcBtnBound.top,
                (int)mArcBtnBound.right,
                (int)mArcBtnBound.bottom);
    }
}
}
```

`mInnerRadius` is radius of center circle button, `mThickness` is height of ambient button in viewgroup. Adding an ambient ImageButton:

```
ArcButton btn = new ArcButton(getContext());
btn.setBackgroundResource(bkgResId);
btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
addView(btn);
btn.rotateTo(10, (mThickness + mInnerRadius) / 2, (mThickness + mInnerRadius));
```

I was reimplement `draw()` method of `ImageButton` class to rotate image view along with background, and provide a public method `rotateTo`.

```
public class ArcButton extends ImageButton {
private float mRotation;
private PointF mPivot;

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(mRotation, mPivot.x, mPivot.y);
    super.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}

public void rotateTo(float rotation, float pivotX, float pivotY) {
    mPivot.x = pivotX;
    mPivot.y = pivotY;
    mRotation = rotation;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        this.setPivotX(pivotX);
        this.setPivotY(pivotY);
        this.setRotation(rotation);
    } else {
        draw(new Canvas());
    }
}
}
```

As you can see the above screenshot, problem is my `Imagebutton` was cutoff. I tried to use `RotateAnimation`, it made rotated buttons were not cutoff but didnt receive touch event too. Android version on testing is 2.2. Can you help me to fix this?

Any other suggestions to rotate ambient buttons effectively are highly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: I think the problem is with Your parent layout where all others are inside. Try to make it bigger..

Comment: I don't think that because of ambient layout, when I make its layout bigger, the background also expanded and overlapped with center button.